# How to calculate an average in android?

Tags: android, average, calculator

I've created in my application a few EditText fields and a button. If you put values in the first and in the 2nd EditText fields, when you press the button, the 3rd EditText field shows the sum of the 2 values you entered. That's working fine, but I want to calculate an average. I mean, if I have 4 EditText fields, I want to enter values in 3 (or less) of them and the 4th to show me the average calculating from the sum divided with the number of the values entered. Example: first value: 2, 2nd value: 4 and the average = 2+4=6/2=3. I want to create the case when a EditText field or more is not enter and the application still can calculate the average. Hope you understand what I want. Thanks !

Here is my:

Medii.java:

```
    package com.cngcnasaud.orar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class Medii extends Activity {

    EditText txtNum1;
    EditText txtNum2;
    EditText txtTotal;
    Button btnCompute;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.medii);

        txtNum1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        txtNum2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        txtTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        btnCompute = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bmedii);

        btnCompute.setOnClickListener(new ClickButton ());

    }


    private class ClickButton implements Button.OnClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int x = Integer.parseInt(txtNum1.getText().toString());
            int y = Integer.parseInt(txtNum2.getText().toString());

            int total = (x + y)/2;

            txtTotal.setText(Integer.toString(total));

        }


    }





}
```

Comment: Only what I posted I had tried. I know how to make the sum and the devide but I don't know how to integrate the number of values the use enter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you have 3 edittexts and the 4th one should display the average. I haven't tested it so there might be some typos.

```
String et1 = editText1.getText().toString();


String et2 = editText2.getText().toString();
String et3 = editText3.getText().toString();
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(et1);
 int num2 = Integer.parseInt(et2);
int num3 = Integer.parseInt(et3);
int calculate = num1 + num2 + num3/3;


 int result = calculate;

editText4.setText(" " + result);
```

Comment: I used your idea and I find how to calculate an average. It's working fine, but only if I fill all the text fields and it's dividing to the number of all text fields, so my application does not detect how many are filled and to how number should divide. Any idea on it? I update my first post. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: You could check with if condition to see if an edittext is empty or not.((et1.length() == 0) &&  (et2.length() > 0) &&  (et3.length() > 0)){ //here if edittext1 is empty and editText2 and 3 are not empty  int calculate = num2 + num3/2;
 }
I just modified my above code. and then you could check with if statement to see if et1 and et2 are not null and et3 is, apply the same formula.Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, it helped me to make an idea about it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Count how many of the fields are not blank, and divide your total by that number. It's probably a good idea to check for blank or not-parsable before you use Integer.parseInt anyways. :)

Comment: I understand how should it be done, and what's in it, but the problem is with the codes.. Can you help me a little bit, please?

Comment: txtNum1.getText().toString() is a String. You can check if it's empty with isEmpty() . Every time you find a string that isn't empty, add one to a counter, then divide the sum by the counter.

Try to write the code, post it, and if it isn't working let us know what happened.

Comment: You get me lost from the first line. Can't you give me an example on my own try from the first post, please? I can't imagine the way I should do it ..

Comment: I update my first post. How to make my application to detect how many text fields are filled and then to divide to the number detected? The average is now working fine. Thanks !

Comment: Glad to hear it's working for you. I'd strongly recommend that you do some basic Java tutorials online (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/ isn't a bad place to start) to learn a bit about objects in Java and the kinds of methods they tend to have. Otherwise you will be constantly frustrated (which won't be fun for you), you'll be constantly asking others to write your code for you (which won't be fun for anyone else), and when something goes wrong you'll have no clue what to do (which won't be fun for anyone at all.)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I did something different:

A single editText and two buttons: Add number and Calculate.

Every time you hit Add number, capture and put it on an Array.

When you hit Calculate, do a loop to sum the whole numbers in a variable, then do the average as sum_variable/array.lenght.

This way you can sum infinite numbers without creating just a static number of fields.

Good luck!

EDIT: Follow code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();
double sum, res;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText editTextNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNum);
    Button buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    Button buttonCalc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCalc);
    final TextView textViewRes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewRes);

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             String numCatch=editTextNum.getText().toString().trim();
                if(numCatch.length() != 0){
                       num.add(numCatch);
                    editTextNum.setText("");
                }
                textViewRes.setText("The average is ");
        }
    });

    buttonCalc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            for(int i=0;i<num.size();i++){
                sum = Integer.parseInt(num.get(i)) + sum;
            }
            res = sum/num.size();
            textViewRes.setText("The average is "+format.format(res));
            res = 0;
            sum = 0;
            num.clear();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'll put the code on my answer. You just have to build a view with one EditText, two Buttons and one TextView, study the code and good luck!